# Mobile site: "Read this post in our app!" Works only with Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I have the "Stack Exchange" app installed on iOS. Often googling leads me to Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange. When the banner in Stack Overflow says: "Read this post in our app!" I click it, and it wants me to install the "Stack Overflow" app. I did, and the mobile link now works, but the "Stack Overflow" iOS app seems to be quite limited in comparison to the Stack Exchange app.

Can the mobile site link the Stack Exchange app or add an addition banner to choose which Stack app to open it in?

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.2.1 (Build 14D27)

Comment: I would prefer the banner to be removed altogether. The app feels less complete and useful than the mobile site.

Comment: @yivi which app are you referring to?